# Indexing of duplicate in aligned time series indices

Tags: python, arrays, duplicates

Say I have two time sequences whose indices are aligned as follows:

```
import numpy as np    

t1_ind = np.array([ 1,  1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  5,  6])
t2_ind = np.array([20, 21, 22, 23, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27])
```

which means that the index 1 of `t1` is aligned with index 20, 21 and 22 of `t2` (implying that `t1` is faster than `t2` in the first three increments) and so on.

The expected output should be:

```
y = np.array(([ 1,  2,  4,  5,  6], 
              [20, 23, 24, 25, 27]))
```

The logic is to "scan" `t1_ind` and `t2_ind` and mark both the *onset* and *offset* of every duplicate segment. In this example, the entry `1` in `t1_ind` is followed by its duplicate, so the onset pair is recorded in `y[:,0]`, and the respective offset pair is `y[:,1]`. The next duplicate segment in `t1_ind` starts and ends as `y[:,3]` and `y[:,4]`, respectively. `t2_ind` is done in the same way, the resulting pairs are `y[:,1]` (won't be recorded twice though) and `y[:,2]`. It seems to me similar with a duplicate-removal problem but I don't know how.

Sorry it is kinda hard for me to think of a proper title and to explain the logic precisely in short. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Shouldn't *3* in `t1_ind`  stay?

Comment: @Psidom 3 is not duplicated and it doesn't mark the offset (for 23 in `t2_ind`, [4, 24] does)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a boolean slice that you can pass to both array, based on the conditions you set up.  Since nothing comes before the first elements, we will always keep the those.  You can check for repeated elements after the first by subtracting slices of the arrays that are shifted by 1.  Doing this for both arrays gives you the boolean array to use as the slice.

```
array_slice = np.concatenate((
     np.array([True]),
     ((t1_ind[1:] - t1_ind[:-1]) != 0) & 
      (t2_ind[1:] - t2_ind[:-1]) != 0)
    ))

array_slice
# returns:
array([ True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

t1_ind[array_slice]
t2_ind[array_slice]
# returns:
array([1, 2, 4, 5, 6])
array([20, 23, 24, 25, 27])
```

Comment: Thanks, it's clever!

Comment: No problem.  Remember to mark the question as complete.